# View Environment functionality in REPL R for Sublimetext 3

Tags: r, sublimetext3, rstudio, sublimerepl

I'm an R studio user looking into switching to SublimeText 3 with the REPL R package.

So far so good but the major difference I see vs. Rstudio is the lack of an "environment" window that shows all the data objects being worked with.  IE the list of dataframes, vectors etc that have been built.

Is is possible to view a list of data objects like this using Sublime Text + REPL R ?

thanks!

Comment: Not as such, no. Remember, Sublime Text is a glorified extendable *text editor*, ***not an IDE***. Therefore, some (many) features from your favorite IDE may be unavailable.

Comment: But then emacs is a glorified extendable text editor, and you can list your R workspace objects by typing Ctrl-C Ctrl-X. Suggest you put in a feature request to the REPL devs, maybe they'll catch up with emacs one day...